# How to Vertically Center Elements of tikz Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, align

Say that I make this table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
  {\hline;
   [20mm] \node{Compute 1}; &[20mm] \node{}; &[20mm] \node{Compute 2};  &[20mm] \node{};  \\
  \hline \\
  \node(January){January}; & \node(February){February} ; & \node(September){September} ; & \node(December){December} ; & \\ 
   \hline \\
   };
  \draw(-7.24,-.68)--(-7.24,.68); 
  \draw(7.24,-.68)--(7.24,.68); 
  \draw(0,-.68)--(0,0);
  \draw(-3.6,-.68)--(-3.6,.68);
  \draw(3.6,-.68)--(3.6,0);
\node(round1)[below left=1cm of January]{Text 1};   
     \draw (-6.20,-0.68)--(round1);
     \node(round2)[below=1cm of February]{Text 2};   
     \draw (-2.3,-0.68)--(round2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not surprisingly, I am new to tikz. My main question is how to center the text in the two rows? In other words, currently `January` is aligned to the left, but `December` is aligned to the right. I want them each centered. Same with `Compute 1` and `Compute 2`.

I am in no way married to the code or style of table I have right now, so if there is a better way to create a better-looking or better-coded table, I am all ears. I just need to have the lines for things like `Text 1` and `Text 2` present in the table. How I get there isn't important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={text width=22mm, text height=1em, text depth=0.25ex,
                    align=center, inner sep=2mm},
             ]
{
Compute 1   &               &   Compute 2   &               \\
January     &   February    &   September   &   December    \\
};
\draw
% horizontal lines
       (M-1-1.north west) -- (M-1-4.north east)
        (M-1-1.south west) -- (M-1-4.south east)
        (M-2-1.south west) -- (M-2-4.south east)
% vertical lines
        (M-1-1.north west) -- (M-2-1.south west)
        (M-1-1.north east) -- (M-2-1.south east)
        (M-2-2.north east) -- (M-2-2.south east)
        (M-2-3.north east) -- (M-2-3.south east)
        (M-1-4.north east) -- (M-2-4.south east)
        ;
\draw   (M-2-1.south) -- + (-1,-1) node[below]  {Text 1};
\draw   (M-2-2.south) -- + ( 1,-1) node[below]  {Text 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

In MWE above in comparison to your MWE are the following changes:

- defined are matrix of nodes
- empty matrix cells are considered as empty nodes
- for nodes are defined common style, where is defined that nodes contents are centered
- all lines of "table" are drawn separately

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a simpler approach using `node`s.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rec/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=1cm},outer sep=0pt]
\node (1) [rec] {Compute 1};
\node (2)   at (1.east)  [rec,anchor=west,minimum width=7.5cm] {Compute 2};
\node (jan) at (1.south) [rec,anchor=north] {January};
\node (feb) at (jan.east)[rec,anchor=west] {February};
\node (sep) at (feb.east)[rec,anchor=west] {September};
\node (dec) at (sep.east)[rec,anchor=west] {December};
\draw [below] (jan.south) -- ++(-1,-1)node{Text 1} (feb.south) -- ++(1,-1)node{Text 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Taken to an extreme, the above idea can be implemented in a loop as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rec/.style={draw,minimum height=.7cm,anchor=west,outer sep=0pt}]    
\foreach \pair/\txt[count=\n] in {{0,.7}/Compute 1,
                                  {2,.7}/Compute 2,
                                  {0,0}/January,
                                  {2,0}/February,
                                  {4,0}/September,
                                  {6,0}/December}
  \node (\txt) at (\pair) [rec,minimum width={\ifnum\n=2 6cm\else2cm\fi}]{\txt};    
\draw [below] (January.south)--++(-.5,-.5)node{Text 1} (February.south)--++(.5,-.5)node{Text 2};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

I would do it using tabular in a minipage and this in a tikzpicture...

Check the code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{array}
    
    
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {
    \begin{minipage}{15cm}
     \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{C{3.1cm}|} }
     \hline
     Compute 1 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Compute 2}\\\hline
     January&February&September&December\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    };
    \draw[thick,-latex] (-5.7,-.5)--(-7.3,-2) coordinate (Text1);
    \draw[thick,-latex] (-2.4,-.5)--(-1.2,-2) coordinate (Text2);
    \node[below left] at(Text1){Text 1};
    \node[below ] at(Text2){Text 2};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

And the result:
[image]

I think it is a clear and simple way with good options on handle positions etc...

I don't think you have to use matrix for this.

Answer (score 3):

A  simple tabular in a `postcript` environment (for `auto-pst-pdf`) and some `nodes` and  `node connections` from  `pst-node` make a short code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{postscript}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{>{\centering}p{2.5cm}|}}
      \hline
      Compute 1 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Compute 2} \\
      \hline
      \rnode{J}{January} & \rnode{F}{February} & September & December \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \psset{nodesepA=3pt, linewidth=0.5pt, labelsep=1.3cm}
    \pnode[0pt, -1.7ex](J){Ju}
    \nput*{-150}{J}{\rnode{TJ}{Text 1}}\nput*{-90}{F} {\rnode{TF}{Text 2}}
    \ncline[nodesepB=0pt]{TJ}{Ju}\ncline[nodesepB=0.7ex]{TF}{F}
  \end{postscript}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]